# Definition of a constant field in Bloch's Effective Java 2nd edition

Tags: java, immutability, effective-java, mutability

Quote:

> If a static final field has a mutable reference type, it can still be
>   a constant field if the referenced object is immutable.

I'm not sure what this mean; can someone give an example of that?

Comment: Effective Java. **Page 238** https://books.google.es/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA238&lpg=PA238&dq=%22static+final+field+has+a+mutable+reference+type%22&source=bl&ots=yZIfJew4P3&sig=tvjvW3oooSNxNRaGF57ru2VwL8c&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-1Z3S5P7LAhULVxoKHRIfCToQ6AEILTAC#v=onepage&q=%22static%20final%20field%20has%20a%20mutable%20reference%20type%22&f=false

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An example that Josh is talking about would be `List`, which is a mutable type (`add()`, `remove()`, etc), but you can assign an *immutable* instance to it:

```
public static final List<String> NAMES = Collections.unmodifiableList( Arrays.asList("foo", "bar")); // immutable
```

---

By the way, a great example of something that *looks* like a constant, but isn't, is a `Date` constant:

```
public static final Date EPOCH = new Date(0);
```

but then some code can do this:

```
EPOCH.setTime(123456789); // oops!
```

`Date` is *mutable*! Everyone will see such a change.

In constrast with this is something like `String`, which *is* immutable:

```
public static final String NAME = "Agent Smith"; // immutable
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a mutable type with an immutable subtype:

```
class Mutable {}  // Not immutable, because it can be extended.

final class Immutable extends Mutable {}

// Reference type is mutable, but referenced object is immutable.
static final Mutable CONSTANT = new Immutable();
```